# In IE, getting error as `no such interface supported` - line - window.open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, window.open, browser-security

I am using IE 11 on windows server 2008 R2 edition.

One of tableau URL i open on IE 11 and then there is a link "Export data".

When click at "Export data", then it gives me javascript error as `no such interface supported`.

when debug the error then it shows line `windows.open(...)` script in .js file.

I have not created tableau page, i don't have any control over there.

This is working fine in all other machines, tested in IE 8, IE 11 at other machine.

Please suggst, how i could resolve this error, what is the configuraiton missing in IE to enable - `Window.open`

Thanks

Comment: https://www.irt.org/script/322.htm

Comment: Check this topic [Title: Microsoft Windows 7 - Cannot Open Hyperlink in New Window Using Internet Explorer 8](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-kc0122623en_us). In my case, registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{79EAC9C5-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B}\ProxyStubClsid32\(Default)` value has been modified to `{79eac9c0-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b}` which should be `{A4A1A128-768F-41E0-BF75-E4FDDD701CBA}`