# Internet Explorer 11 no such interface supported with javascript window.open() function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-11

I have two machines here at work, both are **Windows 7 64 Bit machines** with **Internet Explorer 11** on them.  When visiting any sites that use javascripts `window.open()` command, the following error occurs:

**no such interface supported**

and the page requested is never opened.

From researching this, if found that Microsoft says to install the latest cumulative update for Internet Explorer to fix this problem:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43545

It's already installed on both systems with the problem.  This error still occurs even though with IE patch is installed.  For that matter, all current MS updates/patches have been installed on both systems.

Any ideas on this one??  Not sure what else to try?? Sure, they can use firefox or chrome but sometimes IE has to be used...Argg!!!

**UPDATE**

It appears that **IE 11 version 11.0.9600.17280** doesn't have this problem while **version 11.0.12** does.  Bother running on Windows 7 64 bit machines..

Comment: Do you have a pop up blocker installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149651/in-ie-getting-error-as-no-such-interface-supported-line-window-open

Comment: pop-up blocker is installed but turned off on both machines.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary - Yes, I saw that post and it's for windows server 2008 R2 edition not Windows 7.  No answer that works either.

Comment: Sorry, had wrong OS.. Please see answer below for link to hot fix 2936068

Comment: This one may be useful: [Title: Microsoft Windows 7 - Cannot Open Hyperlink in New Window Using Internet Explorer 8](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-kc0122623en_us)

Answer (score -1):

Verify that you have this Microsoft update installed:

**Windows 7**

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2936068

You can check Control Panel > Programs and Features > View installed updates, and look for 2936068

**Windows 8.1**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2854645

Comment: I've seen this article too and it's for ftp: destinations.  My problem occurs in a normal HTML page which uses window.open() function in javascript. I'll check to see if it's installed anyways.

Comment: I've seen that you've modified the post, will check to see if these patches are installed.

Comment: Interesting - I ran into this a while back when I manually downloaded IE11, but my other Win7 box that got IE11 via Windows updates didn't do it since included the security fix. Installing this KB fixed it for me, but if you still see it after installing hotfix (if not installed), and reboot, you can try the other tricks: hit F12 to open dev tools and check the Console for errors; Add a site to your trusted sites security zone and restart IE and test (remove from trusted sites when done testing!); Create a local html file hosted on local IIS server (assuming IIS installed) and test open()

Comment: All patches and updates have been installed.  Found more systems here at work that run IE 11 Version 11.0.9600.17280 that don't have the problem.  It appears that version 11.0.12 is the version that has this problem.  I tried playing with the security setting in Internet Option too but that didn't help for systems running IE 11 version 11.0.12.

Comment: The answer stands. KB # is the permanent information, and can be googled (or Binged) even if hyperlink (which is only added for convenience) becomes inactive.

Comment: This is worse than useless for developers trying to prevent visitors from encountering the error on their website.

Comment: @catbadger If it's a user error, you can't prevent it. After all, it's a JavaScript error, aka a *client* error.